# utf8_bin vs. utf_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, database, collation, relation

My table Website

```
Website_Name//column name
Google
Facebook
Twitter
Orkut
Frype
Skype
Yahoo
Wikipedia
```

I i use utf8_bin collation then my query to search wikipedia in Website is

```
Select Website_Name from Website where lower(Website_Name)='wikipedia'
```

And if i use utf8_unicode_ci then my select query to search wikipedia in Website is

```
Select Website_Name from Website where Website_Name='wikipedia'
```

Now I want to know which collation is best depending upon the following queries

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It depends on what you need.

The `utf8_bin` collation compares strings based purely on their Unicode [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) values. If all of the code points have the same values, then the strings are equal. However, this falls apart when you have strings with different composition for combining marks (composed vs. decomposed) or characters that are canonically equivalent but don't have the same code point value. In some cases, using `utf8_bin` will result in strings not matching when you expect them to. Theoretically, `utf8_bin` is the fastest because no Unicode normalization is applied to the strings, but it may not be what you want.

`utf8_general_ci` applies Unicode normalization using language-specific rules and compares strings case-insensitively. `utf8_general_cs` does the same, but compares strings case-sensitively.

Comment: so what sould i use .be specific

Comment: As I said, you should make this decision based on what you need. From what I can see about what you're trying to do, I'd go with `utf8_general_ci`, myself.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in using lower() with utf8_bin

Comment: While it is the same thing in English, using `lower()` is not always the same thing as comparing case-insensitively in some languages, and you may run into problems by using `lower()` to compare case-insensitively. I'd stick with using a case-insensitive collation.

Answer (score 16):

Personally I would go with `utf8_unicode_ci`, if you expect that lettercase is generally not important for the results you want to find.

Collations aren't only used at runtime, but also when MySQL builds indexes. So if any of these columns appear in an index, finding data according to the comparison rules of that collation will be pretty much as fast as it ever gets.

In those cases where you do not want case insensitive matching, then do not apply upper or lower. Instead, apply the `BINARY` keyword in front of the utf8 column to force a literal code-point comparison rather than one according to the collation.

```
mysql> create table utf8 (name varchar(24) charset utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, primary key (name));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> insert into utf8 values ('Roland');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into utf8 values ('roland');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'roland' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> select * from utf8 where name = 'roland';
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| Roland |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from utf8 where binary name = 'roland';
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

This should be much faster than using lower or upper, since in those cases, MySQL first needs to make a copy of the column value and modify its lettercase, and then apply the comparison. With BINARY in place it will simply use the index first to find matches, and then do a code-point by code-point comparison untill it finds the values are not equal, which will generally be faster.

Comment: Just a heads up from my experience; using `WHERE BINARY` or `COLLATE utf8_bin` have a negative performance impact on queries that use the PRIMARY KEY when the row is `utf8_general_ci`. Tested on MySQL 5.6.22 & 5.6.10. Issue didn't show up until the database was under decent load.

Answer (score 10):

I was using 'utf8_unicode_ci' which is default by doctrine , i had to change it to :

```
 * @ORM\Table(name = "Table", options={"collate"="utf8_bin"})
```

Since some of my composite primary keys consisted of text fields. Sadly 'utf8_unicode_ci' resolved "poistný" and "poistny" as same primary key value and ended with crash at doctrine inserting flush. I could not simply change collation of one part of composite primary key, had to drop table and recreate. Hope it saves time to someone else..

Comment: This article [utf8_unicode_ci vs utf8_general_ci](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748) explained the differences between `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8_general_ci`