# PHP and sql query coding utf 8 german letters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have problem with getting records from database when I have words with German letters in SQL query, when I do it in phpAdmin it gives 88 rows with results, when I want to execute the same query but in php code it gives me bool(false). In db I use utf8_bin. What is wrong?

```
$getPapers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM swt_pubs WHERE column LIKE '%Aß%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
echo $getPapers;
while ($papers = mysql_fetch_object($getPapers)) {
    echo "string";
    echo convertToUTF8($papers->content);
}
var_dump($papers);?>
```

Results which I get:

> Resource id #6
>
> bool(false)

Edit 1:
I have this coding of page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Edit 2:

```
function convertToUTF8 ($string)
        {
        return str_replace ('Ã„', '&#196;',
               str_replace ('„', '&#132;',
               str_replace ('“', '&#147;',
               str_replace ('–', '&#150;',
               str_replace ('­', '&#173;',
                    str_replace ('È', '&#200;',
                        str_replace ('É', '&#201;',
                            str_replace ('Ö', '&#214;',
                                str_replace ('Ü', '&#220;',
                                    str_replace ('ß', '&#223;',
                                        str_replace ('ä', '&#228;',
                                            str_replace ('è', '&#232;',
                                                str_replace ('é', '&#233;',
                                                    str_replace ('ö', '&#246;',
                str_replace ('ü', '&#252;',
                    str_replace ('@', '&#64;',
                        str_replace ('Ã?', '&#220;',
                            str_replace ('\"', '"',
                            str_replace ("\'","'",
                                ersetzeBbCode ($string)
                                    ))
                                ))
                            )
                        )
                                                                )
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
             ))
            );
        }
```

Comment: Is your PHP source file also encoded in UTF8 or not ? If it is not, the query executed by MyQSL might not be what you wrote in your source code.

Comment: Are you importing a library or do you have a function called `convertToUTF8`? If I had to wager a guess, either that function or `$papers->content` is your issue.

Comment: `convertToUTF8()` is not a PHP function so show us the code for that function

Comment: @the_pete : According to the output, `convertToUTF8` is not called. I don't think it's the issue

Comment: @Mat Yes I think it is, its the `var_dump()` that she forgot to show us

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929836/utf8-bin-vs-utf-unicode-ci might explain why the collation makes the query return no results (the composition of the character `ß` is not the same in the source code than in the DB and utf8_bin compares them blindly while utf8_general_ci is clever)

Comment: @MarcB `mysql_fetch_object` returns false if there are no more rows [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: @Mat: aww, poop. right. that's a post-loop var_dump. apologies...

Comment: I have added function convertToUTF8() var_dump($papers) gives bool(false)

Comment: but it doesn't display even this echo "string";, so it looks like it never gets to this while

Comment: it means that your `query` is invalid or its not returning any results.

Comment: but whenI put this string directly in phpAdmin it gives results back, and in case if would look like that LIKE '%Ab%' it also gives result back,only in case if I use German results it has no results

Comment: To be quite blunt, that `convertToUTF8` is a joke. It has to be. Right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **uft8-general-ci** that solve your problem

Comment: I have changed it, but it didn't help

Comment: Now I see it helped. Before that by hand I changed all AY to ß and it didn't see this letter at all.

Comment: see my another answer that help you upload sql file unicode support

Comment: happy coding and see this page www.tutexp.com

Answer (score 1):

one interesting thing is most of the time we upload large file using sql server but it the file has any unicode character then we get it in any language but the unicode word can't work . to solve this problem when you upload sql file add this life in your sql file :

**SET NAMES utf8;**

then your all problem easily solve