# Query to latin1 column from java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to do a query by title like this:

```
String title = "transfusión";
String sql = "SELECT id FROM graph WHERE title=?";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, title);
st.executeQuery();
```

The problem is that title column charset is **latin1** and my java file encoding is **utf8**. When the title variable contains special caracters like accents, the query never finds a result.

I'm using a MySQL database an the connection url is:

**jdbc:mysql://mysite:3306/mydatabase?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=latin1&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true**

I tried multiple alternatives using **useUnicode=true/false** or **characterEncoding=latin1/utf8/auto** but I never get any result.

Also I tried to convert **title** and **sql** to **ISO-8859-1** before prepare statement like this:

```
title =  new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
sql =  new String(sql.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

**I can't change the database's charset because I'm not the administrator.**

How can I solve that?

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: Note that [PreparedStatement's arguments are 1-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: I would be very surprised if you aren't getting an exception thrown by using `0` as the argument index. Are you catching and suppressing an exception somewhere?

Comment: This should work : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33023792/180100

Comment: If you are using a reasonably recent version of MySQL Connector/J then the JDBC driver should be handling the character set conversions for you based on the character set of the table or column. I just tried a query for 'transfusión' using `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` from my UTF-8 encoded .java file and it found the row in the `latin1` column without complaint. I suspect that there is something else wrong with your code, especially since `setString(0, ...)` will FAIL with "Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 )".

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right, the code is wrong, it is a summary of the original code. I did so to make it easier and I did a mistake. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Table 5.3 MySQL to Java Encoding Name Translations:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

> jdbc:mysql://mysite:3306/mydatabase?autoReconnect=true&**characterEncoding=
>   Cp1252**&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Harlam. Your solution not exactly correct but you have helped me to find the correct one. I have to convert the title variable to **Cp1252** not to **ISO-8859-1** and it works perfectly:

`title = new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1252");`