# utf8_bin vs utf8_general_ci umlaute case insensivity

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, case-sensitive

i am having an issue with german umlaute ä ö ü ... when using match against in my sql query

when i search for "**äpfel**" i get also "**apfel**" when using **utf8_general_ci** but what i want is to just get "**äpfel**", now when i change to **utf8_bin** i get exactly that **BUT its case sensitive**. so **Äpfel** or **Apfel** **will not find äpfel** or **apfel**

i would need *utf8_bin_ci* which does actually not exist i assume?

using utf8_bin with match against and lower(field) or lcase(field) turns out with an error so....what can i do to solve this?

query is like;

```
select * FROM table where MATCH(field) AGAINST ('äpfel')
```

and what i need but does not work is

```
select * FROM table where MATCH(lcase(field)) AGAINST ('äpfel')
```

in utf8_bin

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 1):

Alas, you get a choice between comparing the bits (no case or accent folding) with `..._bin` or both case-folding and accent stripping with all the `..._ci` Collations.

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) provides info what characters are equivalent or not.  For example, in `utf8_german2_ci`, these are treated as equal:

```
    A=a=ª=À=Á=Â=Ã=Å=à=á=â=ã=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą
```

But these come later when sorting:

```
    ae=Ä=Æ=ä=æ
```

Of note:  `_general_ci` never treats a 2-letter pair as equal to a single character, hence `ae` and `æ` are necessarily unequal in `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you need `utf8_bin_ci` but it does not exists, only `utf8_bin` does.

If you want to add case insensitivity, you need to add `LOWER()` to both elements like:

```
mysql> SELECT LOWER('Äpfel') = LOWER('äpfel') COLLATE utf8_bin;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| LOWER('Äpfel') = LOWER('äpfel') COLLATE utf8_bin   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  1 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-> expected result


mysql> SELECT LOWER('Äpfel') = LOWER('apfel') COLLATE utf8_bin;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| LOWER('Äpfel') = LOWER('apfel') COLLATE utf8_bin  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 0 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-> expected result as well
```

Update: Also please have a look at this interesting similar answer: [utf8_bin vs. utf_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929836/utf8-bin-vs-utf-unicode-ci#10929898)

Comment: `*_bin` means binary -- exact equivalence.  `*_bin_ci` would be "exact equivalence, case-insensitive" which is a logical contradiction.  Characters in binary collations are neither upper or lower case, since lettercase is a form of deriving equivalence, and no character is equivalent to any other character in a binary collation.